# CMU pocketsphinx on Mac: GCC throwing errors in stdio.h

Tags: macos, pocketsphinx

I have installed the latest version of both sphinxbase and pocketsphinx on my mac. In this CMU's [site](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx)
they have provided a simple hello world code to test the validity of the installation. The code looks like:

```
#include <pocketsphinx.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ps_decoder_t *ps = NULL;
    cmd_ln_t *config = NULL;

    config = cmd_ln_init(NULL, ps_args(), TRUE,
             "-hmm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us",
             "-lm", MODELDIR "/en-us/en-us.lm.bin",
             "-dict", MODELDIR "/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict",
             NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

and I have to enter this command below to compile using GCC

```
gcc -o hello_ps hello_ps.c \
-DMODELDIR=\"`pkg-config --variable=modeldir pocketsphinx`\" \
`pkg-config --cflags --libs pocketsphinx sphinxbase`
```

where **pkg-config** would take care about include and library paths.

But the compilation returns the following errors in the **stdio.h** file (pocketsphinx.h includes the stdio.h).

```
Restrict requires a pointer or reference (int is invalid)
```

in several places and also

```
Unknown typename _FILE (Expanded from macro 'FILE')
```

I went through stdio.h file and found these corresponding statements and I have no clue what it does. I understand that **restrict** keyword is not a part of C++ standard but even when compiling with **c99**, it still throws the same error. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you compiler is broken, you might try to compile simple program with FILE and stdio.h and see if it works.

Comment: It is working with a simple file reading program.

Comment: And also I tried with other compilers like Clang and the got the same errors again.

Comment: Ok, please add `--verbose` flag to gcc and provide exact compiler output

Comment: There are lots of same repeating errors so I saved it in a text file and posted it in Google drive. I made it publicly visible so feel free to access it. Thank you. The link is: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0ByC-Z20h_ChaVnJBUVhrbFRWVlk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the log you have an extra file `/usr/local/include/stdio.h` which is not a standard include file. This file was installed by some other software and causes problems.

You need to remove problematic stdio.h (and probably other extra headers) from your system.

Correct stdio.h is in `/usr/include folder`.

Comment: Yeah, I just removed the unnecessary files from usr/local/include and it works now. Thank you so much !!